# Integrating Flask-SocketIO with Celery

Tags: python, flask, websocket, celery, flask-socketio

I've built a web application using flask, and i'm currently using celery to run some of the more time intensive tasks as to not hog the single thread Flask runs on and cause delays for other users. I'm looking to send real-time notifications to users on the website when these time consuming tasks are done, one solution I've been trying is Flask-SocketIO, it's pretty simple to set up but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I tried: (Dividing the code blocks into files to further convey the setup of my flask app)

1. run.py:

```
from main import app, socketio
from flask import url_for

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

2. __init__py:

```
#other config code....
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO(app)
#other config code...
from main import routes
```

3. tasks.py:

```
from main import app
from celery import Celery
import logging
from flask import flash
celery = Celery('your_app_name', broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])

@celery.task
def create_background_task():
    # Simulate a time-consuming task
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Done")
    return f"Background task completed for test"
```

4. routes.py:

```
from main.celery import celery
from main.tasks import create_background_task
from main import socketio
from celery.signals import task_postrun
@app.route("/bgtask", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bgtask():
    create_background_task.delay()
    flash("Background task has started.", "info")
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/notifications')
def handle_connect():
    print('User connected')

@task_postrun.connect
def on_task_postrun(sender=None, task_id=None, task=None, **kwargs):
    if task.name == 'main.tasks.create_background_task':
        # Notify the user that the background task is done
        
        print("postrun task done, sending msg to frontend")
        message = "Background task completed"
        socketio.emit('task_done', {'message': message}, namespace='/notifications')
```

5. index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000/notifications');

  socket.on('task_done', function(data) {
      // Log the message to the browser console
      console.log("Task done:", data.message);
  });
</script>
```

I'm getting the "User Connected" message in the terminal, and the task celery is running is being completed correctly, but I can't see anything being outputted in the console log of the website, can anyone please help shed some light on this?

Comment: The Celery worker is a separate process. If you intend to emit a Socket.IO event to a client from the worker, then you have to configure a message queue, so that the worker can communicate with the main server, which controls the socket. Have you read about emitting from auxiliary processes at all in the documentation? I suggest you start from there.